# Webstorm: Have terminal scale to file directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, layout, webstorm

I just switched from VSCode to WebStorm. In VSCode, the directory takes up the entire left side of the view. The terminal is aligned to the bottom, and scales depending on the directory. This gives the directory lots of vertical space.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx8Le.png

In WebStorm it is the oposite, the terminal is aligned to the entire bottom of the screen. The console scales according to the height of the console.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdNWL.png

It turns out that the bottom view container always has scaling priority over that of the left container. I would really like to have WebStorms layout to behave like that of VSCode, where the left container takes scaling priority instead.

So far, I have tried to achieve this by playing with different view modes and anchors, but it seems like the bottom container always takes 100% of the width. The terminal window can be "moved to editor", which creates the result I want, but only with a single terminal window, rather then the entire bottom container.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qsdp.png

Does anyone know how to change the way these views scale?

Comment: Why don't you ask this on the [WebStorm community](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367229-WebStorm)?

Comment: @harrymc Good call, I asked the same question on there now. Their forum questions dont appear on search engines, so having a solution on superuser would be helpful for others.

Comment: If you get a good answer there, you could answer your own question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[With help from Andriy Bazanov, on the Webstorm forum:](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4406793508114/comments/4406796383506)

Simply enable **Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Appearance & Behaviour | Apearance | Widescreen tool window layout**

This maximizes the lenght of vertical windows.